# filling the values of a multidimensional associative array to a html table

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, html-table, associative-array

This is the associative array

```
$newArr=Array ( 
    [565] => Array ( 
        [3] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [1] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [67677] => Array ( 
        [4] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [1] => 1 
            ) 
         ) 
     ) 
    [767] => Array ( 
        [6] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [1] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [76767] => Array ( 
        [7] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [1] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [878] => Array ( 
        [8] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [1] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
        [127] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [1] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [87] => Array ( 
        [7] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [1] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [xyz] => Array ( 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [2] => Array ( 
                [2] => 2 
            ) 
        )
    ) 
    [abc] => Array ( 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [2] => Array ( 
                [1] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
        [4] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [1] => 1 
            )
        ) 
        [5] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [1] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

I want to display it in a html table. The index corresponding to the second column of this associative array will vary 1 to 5 and if the 3rd column corresponding to that 2nd column value doesn't exist, it is to be given NULL or zero.

I have tried the following code but only the values corresponding to the last row of each primary sub-array are printed. (e.g.-

```
abc     1   0   0
        2   0   0
        3   0   0
        4   0   0
        5   1   1
```

This is the code that I've been trying for so long now.

```
foreach($newArr as $key1=>$value1){     
    if(is_array($value1)){
        foreach($value1 as $key2=>$value2){ 
            if(is_array($value2)){ 
                foreach($value2 as $key3=> $value3){
                    if(is_array($value3)){ 
                        foreach($value3 as $key4=> $value4){

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            echo "<td rowspan=5 >". $key1. "</td>";
            for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
                if($key2==$i){
                    echo "<td>". $key2. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>". $key3. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>". $key4. "</td>";
                } else{
                    echo "<td>". $i. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>". 0 . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>". 0 . "</td>";
                }
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }   
}
```

I'm stuck with this one for a while. I'd be thankful if anyone could help me this one!
Don't be too harsh I've gone through the manual corresponding to foreach and the other question similar to this but I'm just unable to do it.
Thanks in advance! Cheers!!

Comment: you are making all those foreach but you don't do anything with them. You have to process some code inside the loops

Comment: @RafaelShkembi by some code do you mean that value-feeding-in-html-table part?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi $key2 corresponds to the second column and it is not NULL my browser is correctly displaying its value

Comment: Yes i miised that. I'am whriting the scipt please wait 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem. The problem is that you are making a foreach loop but not process any code inside it. $key4 will be undifined because it is only availble inside the foreach loop exept if you make a global of it.

```
foreach($newArr as $key1=>$value1){     
if(is_array($value1)){
    foreach($value1 as $key2=>$value2){ 
        $var_key2 = $key2;
        if(is_array($value2)){ 
            foreach($value2 as $key3=> $value3){
                $var_key3 = $key3;
                if(is_array($value3)){ 
                    foreach($value3 as $key4=> $value4){
                        $var_key4 = $key4;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<td rowspan=5 >". $key1. "</td>";
        for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
            if($var_key2 == $i){
                echo "<td>".$var_key2."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$var_key3."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$var_key4."</td>";
            } else{
                echo "<td>". $i. "</td>";
                echo "<td>". 0 . "</td>";
                echo "<td>". 0 . "</td>";
            }
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        $var_key2 = "";
        $var_key3 = "";
        $var_key4 = "";
        echo "</tr>";
    }   
}
```

Comment: $rafael Sir I had tried that one also but it doesn't work either. the structure of the table gets distorted using the above code.

Comment: Try changing the first value of $i. Make it $i = 0

Comment: The first element in array is in position 0, the second one is in position 1 and so on.

Comment: that doesn't help either :( Also I have to print these $i values (which are to be varied from 1 to 5)

Comment: Whats the output from the scipt?

Comment: 565 1 0 0
2 0 0
3 1 1
4 0 0
5 0 0
67677 1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 1 1
5 0 0
767 1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
76767 1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
878 1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
87 1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
xyz 1 2 2
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
abc 1 2 1
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 1 1
5 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0

Comment: but you can see how the values corresponding to abc are repeatiting themselves (the last line of the  previous comment),  there should be only 3 values corresponding to abc

Comment: every time foreach loop runs 5 columns corresponding to that arecreated but we don't always need 5 columns as sometime we want to merge the new entries with the previous sub-array having NULL in those places.

Comment: You can try saving all the values in one other array

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry it will be asking for too much but that doesn't seem to help either as I'll have to fill those 2nd column values varying from 1-5 and corresponding zeros if they are not present in that array.

Won't it make it even more difficult  to iterate through that array?

Comment: Change doesn't seem to help either.
This is actually repeating the 1st column values, what I was doing earlier.
 (eg: abc with the rowspan 5 is repeating itself  3 times for 3 different values) it should come only one time and should contain all the corresponding values.

Comment: as far as I can perceive with every foreach corresponding no. of columns and rows are created and which are printed. We can't undo them or overwrite the values that has already been written in them in the next iteration. :(

Comment: new change doesn't help either as again only the last row of each  primary sub-array is printed, the point where this question started.
Time is a straight circle :D

Comment: yeah I have a few but won't they be omitted after that for($i=1; $i<=5;$i++) loop?
PS: I can't change the database, obviously it's all the result of a sql query.

Comment: will use of while loop instead of for will make a difference?

Comment: please post your query